# test Stage is Being Skipped

Tags: dockerfile

I am new to Docker, and I have the Dockerfile below which Azure Pipelines is using to build an image and push it to an Azure Container Registry.

```
// Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["poc.frontend/poc.frontend.csproj", "poc.frontend/"]
RUN dotnet restore "poc.frontend/poc.frontend.csproj"
COPY ["Tests/poc.frontend/poc.frontend.unittests/poc.frontend.unittests.csproj", "poc.tests/"]
RUN dotnet restore "poc.tests/poc.frontend.unittests.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/poc.frontend"
RUN dotnet build "poc.frontend.csproj" -c Release

FROM build AS test
LABEL test=true
WORKDIR "/src/poc.tests"
RUN dotnet build "poc.frontend.unittests.csproj" -c Release
RUN dotnet test --test-adapter-path "bin/Release/net6.0/NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll" -c Release --results-directory /testresults --logger "trx;LogFileName=test_results.trx" "poc.frontend.unittests.csproj"

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR "/src/poc.frontend"
RUN dotnet publish "poc.frontend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "poc.frontend.dll"]
```

When the build pipeline uses this Dockerfile as part of the Docker@2 task, it skips the test part. After building the application it goes immediately to the publish part.

```
// build-template.yaml
// ... other tasks
    
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: 'Build and push an image to ACR'
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: ${{parameters.imageRepository}}
        dockerFile: ${{parameters.dockerFile}}
        containerRegistry: sc-acr-sp
        buildContext: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        tags: v$(Build.BuildId)
```

These are what the logs are showing.

```
...
#17 [build 9/9] RUN dotnet build "poc.frontend.csproj" -c Release
#17 0.285 MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
#17 1.000   Determining projects to restore...
#17 1.398   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 18735.00 MB out of 74244.00 MB, Memory: Used 883.00 MB out of 6932.00 MB, CPU: Usage 15.91%
#17 3.825 /src/poc.frontend/Repositories/Mock/MockBasketRepository.cs(15,35): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/src/poc.frontend/poc.frontend.csproj]
#17 3.826 /src/poc.frontend/Repositories/Mock/MockBasketRepository.cs(22,35): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/src/poc.frontend/poc.frontend.csproj]
#17 3.939   poc.frontend -> /src/poc.frontend/bin/Release/net6.0/poc.frontend.dll
#17 3.956 
#17 3.956 Build succeeded.
#17 3.957 
#17 3.957 /src/poc.frontend/Repositories/Mock/MockBasketRepository.cs(15,35): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/src/poc.frontend/poc.frontend.csproj]
#17 3.957 /src/poc.frontend/Repositories/Mock/MockBasketRepository.cs(22,35): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread. [/src/poc.frontend/poc.frontend.csproj]
#17 3.957     2 Warning(s)
#17 3.957     0 Error(s)
#17 3.957 
#17 3.957 Time Elapsed 00:00:03.53
#17 DONE 4.0s

#18 [publish 1/2] WORKDIR /src/poc.frontend
#18 DONE 0.0s

...
```

What should I do so that the test stage doesn't get ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Docker Engine earlier than version 23.0, the legacy Docker Engine builder processes all stages of a Dockerfile leading up to the selected **`--target`**. It will build a stage even if the selected target doesn't depend on that stage.

However, since Docker Engine 23.0, **BuildKit** is the default builder for users. **BuildKit** only builds the stages that the target stage depends on.

For your case, with **BuildKit** enabled (**DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1**):

- The target stage (**`final`**) depends on '**`base`**' (`FROM base AS final`) and '**`publish`**' (`COPY --from=publish /app/publish .`) stages.
- The '**`publish`**' depends on '**`build`**' stage (`FROM build AS publish`). So, the target stage also is determined to depend on '**`build`**' stage.
- The '**`test`**' stage is not depended on by the target stage, and the other stages depended on by the target stage also does not depend on the '**`test`**' stage.

So, finally, only the '**`base`**', '**`build`**', '**`publish`**' and '**`final`**' stages are executed when building the Dockerfile.

---

To disable **BuildKit**, you can use one of the following methods:

1. Set the pipeline variable below. It will map/override the environment variable with the new value "**DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0**".

   ```yaml
   variables:
     DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 0
   ```
2. Directly add "**DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0**" before the "**`docker build`**" command. It will build Dockerfile with BuildKit disabled.

   ```bash
   DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build xxx
   ```

---

Related documentations:

- [**BuildKit**](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/)
- [**Multi-stage builds**](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#differences-between-legacy-builder-and-buildkit)

---

**EDIT:**

If you do not want to disable **BuildKit**, you can try to set up a job in pipeline to specifically run the tests and publish the test results outside of the **`Dockerfile`**:

1. Use the default **checkout** task to check out the code files of your C# projects.
2. Use the [**DotNetCoreCLI**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task to run the related **`dotnet`** commands, such as **`dotnet build`**, **`dotnet test`**, etc...

   ```yaml
   - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
     displayName: 'dotnet test'
     inputs:
       command: test
       projects: poc.frontend.unittests.csproj
       arguments: '-c Release --test-adapter-path "bin/Release/net6.0/NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll" --results-directory "./testresults" --logger "trx;logfilename=test_results.trx"'
       publishTestResults: false
   ```

   You also can use a script task (such as [**Bash**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines), [**PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines), [**CmdLine**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines), etc..) to execute the related commands.

   ```yaml
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'dotnet test'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          dotnet test "poc.frontend.unittests.csproj" \
          -c Release \
          --test-adapter-path "bin/Release/net6.0/NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll" \
          --results-directory "./testresults" \
          --logger "trx;logfilename=test_results.trx"
   ```
3. Use the [**PublishTestResults**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-test-results-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops&tabs=trx%2Ctrxattachments%2Cyaml) task to publish the test results to Azure Pipelines.

Below is a sample of the test job.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: test
  displayName: 'Run unittests'
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet test'
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: poc.frontend.unittests.csproj
      arguments: '-c Release --test-adapter-path "bin/Release/net6.0/NUnit3.TestAdapter.dll" --results-directory "./testresults" --logger "trx;logfilename=test_results.trx"'
      publishTestResults: false

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: VSTest
      testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/testresults'
```

---

Comment: Bright Ran-MSFT, are there any Microsoft documentation that provide information on how to execute unit tests properly in an Azure pipeline when using Dockerfile? I rather not disable the Buildkit option.

Comment: @Sohlae, If you do not want to disable **BuildKit**, you need to run the tests outside of the `Dockerfile`. I have updated my above answer with more details about how to run the tests and publish test results in pipeline (see **EDIT**).

Comment: Bright Ran-MSFT, thank you for the additional information. If I do it outside the Dockerfile then I need to also execute `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` to generate the necessary .dll files for running the unit tests such as the testadapter.dll, am I correct? 

If yes, then running restore/build both inside and outside the Dockerfile will cause the pipeline to run for a longer time. Let me know your thoughts, please.

Comment: @Sohlae, Yes. the `restore` and `build` processes are required. By default, when running the '`dotnet test`' command to the test project, it will automatically run the '`dotnet restore`' and '`dotnet build`' commands to build the test project and the projects referenced by the test project. More details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#implicit-restore).

Comment: @Sohlae, If you do not want to take longer time, in the `Dockerfile`, you can consider combining the steps run in `Test` stage into the `Build` stage. Otherwise, you need to disable **BuildKit**.

Comment: Bright Ran-MSFT, thank you.